# How do I detect ViewModel binding errors in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, validation

Let's say I have a ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel { public DateTime? InvoiceDate { get; set; } }
```

and this ViewModel is bound to a text box:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding InvoiceDate}" />
```

Now when the user enters `2015/01/01`, InvoiceDate is 2015/01/01. When the user then changes his input to something invalid, e.g. `2015/1234`, InvoiceDate is *still* 2015/01/01. This makes sense, since `2015/1234` cannot be converted to a `DateTime?`.

However, I want to detect this case and prevent the user from executing a command while invalid data (which cannot be converted to the ViewModel type) is entered. How do I detect this case? I'm sure there's a simple one-liner (like `this.AllDataBindingsAreValid()`), but I cannot find it.

```
void MyCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = this.AllDataBindingsAreValid(); // What's it really called?
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `IDataErrorInfo`, you would find it if you search for [c# binding validation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/63646/1997232).

Comment: You might be looking for something like the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors

Comment: Or maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/231052/1997232) one?

Comment: @Sinatr that does solve the problem, however it is not the answer to the question

Comment: @Sinatr: I don't need to implement custom validation logic here. I just want to detect when the *default WPF data binding conversion* failed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting WPF Validation Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
private void CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = IsValid(sender as DependencyObject);
}

private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
{
    // The dependency object is valid if it has no errors and all
    // of its children (that are dependency objects) are error-free.
    return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) &&
    LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj)
    .OfType<DependencyObject>()
    .All(IsValid);
}
```

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127477/detecting-wpf-validation-errors) post
.

Comment: Thanks, but I *think* this only works when a ValidationRule is set in the binding. But I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Instead of directly copying the answer you could also close as duplicate.