# Disabling a save button if validation result is false, by using custom ValidationRule

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, mvvm

I saw:

[Using WPF Validation rules and disabling a 'Save' button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231052/using-wpf-validation-rules-and-disabling-a-save-button)

Two proposed solutions use [IDataErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx)
or attaching a handler to `Validation.ErrorEvent` through
`Validation.AddErrorHandler()`. AddErrorHandler takes two parameters, the dependency object and the handler. Since I'm doing this in the ViewModel, and have no reference to the DO, how can I achieve this by using my custom rule for validation.

The validation rule:

```
public class NameValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {    
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((string)value)))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Must not be empty");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

And the control that uses it:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Customer.FirstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:NameValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveAddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Customer}"/>
```

So, is there an 'MVVM' way to change the `CanExecute` of the `SaveAddCommand` when the text box validation rule returns false, without needing to supply the dependency object in the code behing to the `AddHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
 public class NameValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((string)value)))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Must not be empty");
               ButtonSave.IsEnabled = false;
            }

            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
```

I hope it works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have your `Command` implementation Raising `CanExecuteChanged` this will re query the commands `CanExecute` method.
If you can your `MainViewModel` could be aware of the child vm's, like customer, changes, i.e. by creating event on the `Customer` VM. So when the property is being set in the `Customer` the `MainViewModel` can then raise `CanExecuteChanged` and reevaluate the condition for specified Command. This will eliminate the need for custom validation all together leaving `MainViewModel` `Command` controlling the Availability of the button, like `WPF` expects it to be.
HTH
P.S. Let us know if you need more help, happy coding
EDIT: this is assuming that your `MainViewModel` has the `SaveAddCommand`.